# Main difference between const and Non-const member function

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
void showDist() const { 
}
```

and

```
void showDist() {
}
```

and what is the benefit of `const` here?

Answer (score 2):

`const` says that you will not modify <strike>any of the member variables of the object</strike> (or more correctly `*this`). Note that `this` is not the same as `const this`. `const` pointers and non-`const` pointers are incompatible.

If you have a `const` object, you **must** provide a const overload.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // Remove this and see the compiler error
    void foo() const 
    {
        std::cout << "Const.";
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Non-const.";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const Foo foo;
    foo.foo();
}
```

Comment: to put it more in laymen's terms: a class written with *proper* const awareness is more useful (usable in more situations) than one that is not

Comment: @imsoconfused Fitting name.

Comment: thanks, i was startled by my insight just now too

Comment: a non const pointer may be assigned to a const pointer, so saying they are incompatible is an oversimplification.  For thoroughness, a const object may have it's `mutable` data members modified.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a class `X`.
The only difference is:
In a non-`const` member function, the type of `this` is:

```
X*
```

In a `const` member function, the type of `this` is:

```
const X*
```

That's it.
Because of this, the `const` member function

1. isn't allowed to modify any member of the class `X` except for the members that are `mutable`.
2. isn't allowed to call any non-`const` member function of the class `X`.